# Incorrect expiry time for subscription in Google Play Billing

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-subscription, google-play-billing

I have a problem with real-time notifications from Google Play Billing.

At `1609879039 (01-05-2021)` user bought a 3-day trial subscription.

On backend-server I got a purchase notification from Google with end of user subscription expiry time `1610143344 (01-08-2021)` (expiryTimeMillis field form subscription's purchase object).

But next real-time notification for this user I only got at `1610231839 (01-09-2021)` with
`expiryTimeMillis = 1610308949 (01-10-2021)`.
Value of `expiryTimeMillis` - incorrect. Cause for this subscription I got `7 days grace period`.

So I have two problems:

1. Google send Grace-Period notification with one-day late
2. When I received the Grace-Period notification, the subscription that linked to this notification contain incorrect `expiry time`.

PS:
When I call by hand this method https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get to get user subscription's expiration time I got correct `expiryTimeMillis = 1610455205968 (01-12-2021)`.

Can anyone help?

Update:
this case is reproduce for Trial subscriptions.